# Using SimpleSAML as SP and IDP for development environnement

Tags: php, saml, saml-2.0

I am trying to authenticate using SAML in my web app.

I followed the [IdP quick start](http://simplesamlphp.org/docs/1.9/simplesamlphp-idp#section_2) and the [SP quick start](http://simplesamlphp.org/docs/1.9/simplesamlphp-sp) user guides and came up woth the configuration below 
which fails with :

```
Backtrace:
1 /app_path/application/lib/simplesamlphp/www/_include.php:37 (SimpleSAML_exception_handler)
0 [builtin] (N/A)
Caused by: Exception: Unable to find the current binding.
Backtrace:
2 /app_path/application/lib/simplesamlphp/lib/SAML2/Binding.php:81 (SAML2_Binding::getCurrentBinding)
1 /app_path/application/lib/simplesamlphp/modules/saml/lib/IdP/SAML2.php:266 (sspmod_saml_IdP_SAML2::receiveAuthnRequest)
0 /app_path/application/lib/simplesamlphp/www/saml2/idp/SSOService.php:19 (N/A)
```

**Setup :**

- My app runs locally with the host :  trunk.sam.net
- Simplesaml, SP, is included in the app as a library and accessible at : trunk.sam.net/simplesaml
- Simplesaml, IdP, is installed locally and runs at : auth.sam.net

Both simplesaml are actually using the same code and configuration files (they share the same document root)

**Configuration :**

**config.php**

```
'enable.saml20-idp'     => true,
'enable.shib13-idp'     => true,
```

**authsources.php**

```
'default-sp-trunk.sam.net' => array(
    'saml:SP',
    'entityID'    => 'http://trunk.sam.net',
    'idp'         => 'http://auth.sam.net/simplesaml/saml2/idp/metadata.php',
    'ssoPortalUrl'=> 'http://auth.sam.net/simplesaml/saml2/idp/SSOService.php',
    'bkmapping'   => array(
        'login'     => 'uid',
        'eMail'     => 'mail'
    )
),


'example-userpass' => array(
    'exampleauth:UserPass',
    'shf:pwd' => array(
        'uid' => array('shf'),
        'eduPersonAffiliation' => array('mail', 'shf@bk-soft.com')
    ),
    'shl:pwd' => array(
        'uid' => array('shl')
    ),
),
```

**saml20-idp-hosted.php**

```
$metadata['__DYNAMIC:1__'] = array(
/*
 * The hostname for this IdP. This makes it possible to run multiple
 * IdPs from the same configuration. '__DEFAULT__' means that this one
 * should be used by default.
 */
'host' => '__DEFAULT__',

/*
 * The private key and certificate to use when signing responses.
 * These are stored in the cert-directory.
 */
'privatekey' => 'server.pem',
'certificate' => 'server.crt',

/*
 * The authentication source which should be used to authenticate the
 * user. This must match one of the entries in config/authsources.php.
 */
'auth' => 'example-userpass',

/*
 * The interoperable SAML 2 profile specifies that attributes should be delivered using the urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri NameFormat. 
 * We therefore recommended enabling this in new installations. This can be done by adding the following to the saml20-idp-hosted configuration:
 */
'attributes.NameFormat' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri',
'authproc' => array(
    // Convert LDAP names to oids.
    100 => array('class' => 'core:AttributeMap', 'name2oid'),
),
```

);

**saml20-idp-remote.php**

```
$metadata['http://auth.sam.net/simplesaml/saml2/idp/metadata.php'] = array (
    'entityid' => 'http://auth.sam.net/simplesaml/saml2/idp/metadata.php',
    'contacts' => 
    array (0 => 
        array (
            'contactType' => 'technical',
            'surName' => 'Administrator',
            'emailAddress' => array (0 => 'support@bluekiwi-software.com'),
       ),
  ),
  'metadata-set' => 'saml20-idp-remote',
  'SingleSignOnService' => array (0 => array (
      'Binding' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect',
      'Location' => 'http://auth.sam.net/simplesaml/saml2/idp/SSOService.php',
  ),
),
'SingleLogoutService' => 
array ( 0 =>  array (
    'Binding' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect',
    'Location' => 'http://auth.sam.net/simplesaml/saml2/idp/SingleLogoutService.php',
  ),
),
'ArtifactResolutionService' => 
array (
),
'keys' => 
array (0 =>  array (
    'encryption' => false,
    'signing' => true,
    'type' => 'X509Certificate',
    'X509Certificate' => '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',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'encryption' => true,
    'signing' => false,
    'type' => 'X509Certificate',
    'X509Certificate' => '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',
  ),
),
```

);

**saml20-sp-remote.php**

```
$metadata['http://trunk.sam.net'] = array (
  'AssertionConsumerService' => 'http://trunk.sam.net/simplesaml/module.php/saml/sp/saml2-acs.php/default-sp-trunk.sam.net',
  'SingleLogoutService' => 'http://trunk.sam.net/simplesaml/module.php/saml/sp/saml2-logout.php/default-sp-trunk.sam.net',
);
```

Could anyone point me to what I did wrong ?

Am i missing a configuration entry / file ?

Should I use separate simplesaml installations ?

Thanks for your advice

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem was that the SP and IdP need to be two different installations of simple saml.
I copied the source code to another folder, edited the vhost I used for the IdP (auth.sam.net) and everything worked. The configuration was OK.

Answer (score 0):

What does your simpleSAML IDP authenticate against? AD?

Do you simply want your application to authenticate against the IDP repository?

Why do you need the simpleSAML SP?

Could your application authenticate directly against the simpleSAML IDP?

You normally use simpleSAML SP in something like the following:

AD <-- ADFS <-- simpleSAML SP <-- SAML application.

Comment: The IDP authentifies against a stub (a text file listing user and passwords) as the whole setup is for dev and test purposes.

Comment: OK - same question - Why do you need the simpleSAML SP?

Comment: @nzpcmad Unfortunately simplesaml doesn't have good documentation for newbie. :( I am am also struggling. I want to authenticate my php application with OKTA so i have used simplesamlphp. But unable to succeed. Appreciate your help if you can on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51253189/how-apache-know-that-saml-response-is-authenticated